# Почему не выводится изображение?

Tags: php, html, bootstrap

Есть такая проблема: На страничке выводиться типа превью изображения, по клику на это изображение должно открыться модальное окно с большой версией картинки. Только вот превью выводится нормально, а модальное окно пустое, картинки в нем нет.
Вот исходник:

```
else echo '<a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><img src="' .$row['small']. '" /></img></a>';?>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>  
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">  <img src="<? echo $row['big'] ;?>"/></img></div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" align="center">Закрыть</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

А вот код уже сформированной браузером страницы:

```
<a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><img src="images/small/2016042513164195.jpg" /></img></a>                 
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>  
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">  <img src="images/big/2016042513164147.jpg"/></img>'</div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" align="center">Закрыть</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Источник изображения в переменных $row['big'] и $row['small'] верный, изображения есть, папки есть. Более того, если щелкать по ссылкам во view-source, во время просмотра кода готовой страницы, то все открывается. Но вот в модальном окне картинки как не было так и нет. Что я сделал не так?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего дело в том, что используется относительный путь

> images/big/2016042513164147.jpg

Попробуйте задействовать абсолютный путь (от корня сайта)

> /images/big/2016042513164147.jpg

В этом случае вы сможете ссылаться на изображение из любого вложенного роута. В противном случае для каждого уровня вложения папок на сайте, вам придется вычислять корректный относительный путь к изображению.

Comment: Хм, интересно. Сделал так, как вы сказали <img src="/<? echo $row['big'] ;?>"/></img>, теперь есть иконка, типа там должно быть изображение, но его нет

Comment: А в браузере изображение открывается по пути http://yoursite.ru/images/big/2016042513164147.jpg?

Comment: Вот что интересно, если кликаю правой кнопкой мыши на любом месте страницы и выбираю пункт "Просмотр кода страницы", то я вижу то, что написал в самом вопросе (view-source) и там все сылки валидны, если на них кликать, то все открывается и работает. Но вот если клинуть правой кнопкой и выбрать пункт "Просмотреть код", то открывается консоль разработчика (так ведь это называется?) и вот тут уже тег img пустой, ну не совсем, он выглядит так <img src="/">, а во view-source так <img src="/images/big/2016042513164147.jpg">

Comment: JavaScript не может путь корректироваться?

Comment: Не знаю, а как проверить? Я сам js не использую, его использует bootstrap